# Wordpress: How to change name of ADD-ON domain's folder and also change/rename all references to it

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, directory, wp-config, subdomains

Interserver.net hosting allows install of unlimited sites in one user account. I have set up an **"add-on" domain**, which is a fairly common structure but **different than using WP Multi-site**. Content for add-on domains are stored in separate folders outside of the public_html folder, and referenced from subdomains in the public_html folder (such as subdomain.maindomain.com).

I changed the external folder's original name (tt.subdomain.com) to a simpler new folder name (subdomain). However, I'm not able to access contents and functionality fully unless I use the original folder name.

I'm making things work right now using redirects and original subdomain url. But I REALLY want to get rid of all reference to the original name of the folder. I was hoping that just changing the folder name would work, but nope!

I'm thinking I have to somehow update the original folder name (tt.example.com) to changed folder name (example) within databases, etc. Gratefully, I only have one simple page created on the site, so hopefully it won't require a lot of work.

After I renamed the folder (to "example") I fiddled around with deleting it, and then trying to install a new add-on domain site with "example" as its install folder name, but it seemed that it was getting messed up by remnant connections to parts of the earlier install. I don't remember the exact issues. Maybe I needed to also wait a day for deletion to propagate across the net before trying to reuse the same folder name--not sure.

Help?

Comment: this is a hosting issue, not a wordpress issue.  You'll need to login to your server and change the directory to where the subdomain is pointing.

Comment: I can't tell: is your add on domain run by WordPress or is it just static files you want to serve separately?